# Application Insights on a large SaaS

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a large Multi-Tenant Saas running on Azure. Where I have individual deployments of our application for each tenant (Web App, SQL, and Storage). Would you create 1 Application Insight instance for ALL the tenants so you can consolidate your logs or would you have individual App Insights?

We have a lot of tenants so would this make sense?

Comment: It seems that it would be best to have 1 App Insight instance for all deployments since it shows up in Visual Studio and would be easier to track. I am sure there is a way to probably track which deployment it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this doc: [Should I use single or multiple Application Insights resources?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/troubleshoot-faq#should-i-use-single-or-multiple-application-insights-resources), here is the content:

> Use a single resource for all the components or roles in a single
>   business system. Use separate resources for development, test, and
>   release versions, and for independent applications.

And if you have to use multi application insights instances, please don't worry, you can also use [application insights cross-query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query#identifying-an-application) for querying from multi application insights.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is semi clear there , since we will have hundreds of deployments if not in the thousands. So I am still on the fence.